# Javax.ws.rs.BadRequestExcection not working in Spring Rest

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

In restEasy I used this BadRequestExcrption to throw the error but in Spring Rest it's not working. Please specify any method to throw 400 error in Spring Rest.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own `BadRequestException` class and throw it.

Here is an example:

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException{

  public BadRequestException() {
      super();
  }

  public BadRequestException(final String message, final Throwable cause) {
      super(message, cause);
  }

  public BadRequestException(final String message) {
      super(message);
  }

  public BadRequestException(final Throwable cause) {
      super(cause);
  }
}
```

You can specify your own status code in `@ResponseStatus`

Comment: Thank you. But I need to have super(message, ResponseEntity.status()) kind of thing.